# PayPal field and decimal error in node.js

Tags: javascript, paypal

When I tried these values in price and amount fields, it gives an error. It works fine if the value is not a float or decimal: 
**code** :

```
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
        "return_url": "http://localhost:2300/success",
        "cancel_url": "http://localhost:2300/cancel"
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items": [{
                "name": "Item",
                "sku": "Item",
                "price": '0.0015',
                "currency": "INR",
                "quantity": 1
            }]
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "INR",
            "total": '0.0015'
        },
        "description": 'Item description.'
    }]
};
```

**Error** : 
`response:
   { name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
     message: 'Invalid request - see details',
     debug_id: 'f42749ec22229',
     information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors',
     details: [ [Object] ],
     httpStatusCode: 400 },
  httpStatusCode: 400 }`

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you transfer a fraction of a penny?

Comment: It goes same with 100.0015 or 200.0015 or anything with decimal or float.

Comment: And what is in the `details` object in error?

Comment: Details : [ { field: 'transactions.item_list.items',
    location: 'body',
    issue:
     'Cannot construct instance of `com.paypal.platform.payments.model.rest.common.Item`, problem: INVALID_CURRENCY_AMOUNT_FORMAT' } ]

Answer (score 0):

You should be printing out `details: [ [Object] ],`  If you look into that details array of the JSON response, it should say `INVALID_CURRENCY_AMOUNT_FORMAT`

Most PayPal-supported currencies, `INR` included, only allow two decimal places, i.e. nothing smaller/beyond `.01`

Comment: Then what can I do about this? I may need more than two digits after decimal.

Comment: Well you could see if there is any other payment provider that allows smaller than `.01` amounts for `INR`, but my guess would be there are few or none.  Essentially you are expected to round everything to the nearest cent when submitting a transaction for processing.  If individual items are the only things with partial cent values.  Another thing you could do it omit that line item data -- or, perhaps, clump quantities into a composite item that is rounded to a nearest cent.

Comment: But it is same with USD too.

Comment: Yes, all the same applies to USD.  And it will be the same with almost all currencies.  It is rare for a currency to support thousandths (`.001`) or beyond, which is why you need to round to the nearest `.01`

Answer (score 0):

It worked! Thank you all for help.
I used **"Math.round((100.01151)*100)/100;"** for **price** and **total amount** which gives 100.01.